# sorting Grid View column with foreign key to different entity using LINQto SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

In this Implementation we have to entities "Company" and "Corporate".After connecting to the database i used the LINQ to SQL designer to create entity objects. The main page for the company entity is to show the corporate it belongs to ; so in the grid we will have these columns:

**CompanyName | CorporateName | Description**

the company table only has a corporate ID and not a corporate Name; but LINQ gives the ability to load a corporate object and access the name of the corporate record.

since sorting is enabled for the grid columns , a user can click on a column to order the results by that column (DESC or ASC)

the sorting works fine for **CompanyName** and **Description** but will not work for **CorporateName **!

below is the code for sorting the grid data

var entityType = typeof(Entities.Company);

```
        //load company list based on Business Unit selected
        var companyList = LoadCompanyRecords());// return type IQueryable<Entities.Company>

        //if filters are used -> filter the results
        companyList = FilterResults(companyList);//return type is IQueryable<Entities.Company>

        // order by work flow starts
        const string ascSortMethodName = "OrderBy";
        const string descSortMethodName = "OrderByDescending";
        var sortMethod = ascSortMethodName;
        var orderdirection = GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);

        if (orderdirection == "DESC")
            sortMethod = descSortMethodName;

        //var entityType = typeof(Entities.Company);
        var property = entityType.GetProperty(e.SortExpression);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "p");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);

        MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(
                                           typeof(Queryable),
                                           sortMethod,
                                           new Type[] { entityType, property.PropertyType },
                                           companyList.Expression,
                                           Expression.Quote(orderByExp));

        var result = companyList.Provider.CreateQuery<Entities.Company>(resultExp);

        gvAssets.DataSource = result;
        gvAssets.DataBind();
```

has anybody ran into this before ? and whats best way to deal with sorting a column that do not belong to current entity? 
or should i think about writing an sql join query or may be  a stored procedure ?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

A temporary solution to this was to check for that column name and make sure that it has its own sorting functionality as below  :

var sortColumn = e.SortExpression;

```
        if (sortColumn == "CorporateGroupName")
        {
            if (orderdirection == "DESC")
                result = companyList.OrderByDescending(x => x.CorporateGroup.CorporateGroupName).ToList();
            else
                result = companyList.OrderBy(x => x.CorporateGroup.CorporateGroupName).ToList();
        }
```